# Angular 2 changing one variable value affects another in the loop

Tags: angular

### Staff.html

```
<div class="teacher-lists teacher" *ngFor="let staff of TotalData">
          <div class="photo-div">
            <img *ngIf="staff?.staffImage[0]?.secure_url" [src]=staff?.staffImage[0]?.secure_url/>
          </div>
          <div class="name-div">
            <h1 class="teacher-name">{{staff.teacherName}}</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="phone-div">
            <h1 class="teacher-name">{{staff.phoneNumber}}</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="acticons students">
            <a (click)="editStaff(staff)" class="link-block-2 w-inline-block" style="cursor:pointer">
              <img src="assets/images/edit.svg" data-ix="edit-popup">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

### staff.component.ts

```
export class ViewAllComponent implements OnInit {
 public TotalData: any;
 public canEditStaff: boolean = false;
 public editStaffData: any = {};
 public showLoading: boolean = false;

getStaffs(min: any = 0, limit: any = '') {

this.api.post('getAllStaffs', { role: "Teaching", limit: limit, min: min })
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    this.TotalData = data;
    console.log('success', data)
  },
  error => console.log(error)
  )
}

editStaff(staff) {
this.editStaffData.staffInfo = staff;
this.canEditStaff = !this.canEditStaff; 
}

closeStaff() {
this.canEditStaff = !this.canEditStaff;
}

saveStaff(registrationData, form) {
this.api.post('update-teachers', registrationData)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    if (data.success) {
      form.resetForm();
      this.getStaffs();
      this.closeStaff();
      this.showLoading = false;
    }
    console.log('success', data)
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.showLoading = false;
  });
}

}
```

### edit staff popup

```
<div class="edit-overlay" *ngIf="canEditStaff">
<div class="teacher-edit w-clearfix">
<a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="closeStaff()" class="close-edit w-inline-block" data-ix="colse-edit">
</a>
<div class="form-container">
  <h1 class="form-title">Edit staff</h1>
  <div class="underline"></div>
  <div class="w-form">

    <form name="email-form-2" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveStaff(editStaffData.staffInfo,form)" class="form">
      <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-6">
          <div class="col-field-1">
            <label for="name" class="field-label">Teacher Name</label>
            <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z .a-z]{2,}" [(ngModel)]="editStaffData.staffInfo.teacherName" class="text-field w-input" name="name" data-name="Name" placeholder="Nmae">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-row">
          <div class="w-col w-col-6">
            <div class="col-field-1 w-clearfix">
              <label for="name-6" class="field-label">Staff Photo</label>
              <input type="text" *ngIf="!editStaffData.staffInfo.staffImage.length" class="text-field w-input required" maxlength="256" name="name-2" data-name="Name 2" placeholder="Student Photo" readonly [(ngModel)]="editStaffData.photoName">
              <input type="text" *ngIf="editStaffData.staffInfo.staffImage.length>0" readonly class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="name-2" data-name="Name 2" placeholder="Student Photo" [(ngModel)]="editStaffData.photoName">
              <input type="file" name="file" #fileInput id="file_input_id" (change)="upload()" [multiple]="false" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display:none;" />
              <label for="file_input_id" class="upload-image w-inline-block" style="cursor:pointer"></label>
              <p *ngIf="photoError" style="color:#dd2c00">{{photoError}}</p>
              <p *ngIf="photoSuccess" style="color:#42A948">Photo successfully saved</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w-col w-col-6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button *ngIf="!showLoading" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="save-button w-button">SUBMIT</button>
        <div *ngIf="showLoading" class="save-button w-button loading">Please Wait...</div>
        <p *ngIf="editStaffData.saveError" class="success-message">Please verify all fields</p>
        <p *ngIf="editStaffData.saveSuccess" class="success-message">Staff saved successfully</p>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="w-form-done">
      <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-form-fail">
      <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-line"></div>
```

> if we edit anything in the pop-up the values in the background data will also gets changed but not in the database.if i close the pop-up the changed data will gets visible in the background(original). if i refresh the page the old(original) data is back. so my question is why and how the data in the background also gets changed though i'm not using any common variables and no function calling for saving.
>
> This is my original data
>   [image]
>
> This is the pop-up i'm editing. now i change teacher name and delete phone number. then i close the pop-up without saving

[image]

> and see the original data that's also gets changed.

[image]

> this is my doubt how the original data in the loop gets changed without saving or using common variables.

Thanks in advance to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because there is two-way data binding. When UI elements get updated, the changes get propagated back to the model (thats why your original data in the loop has changed). You can prevent this  by sending a copy of staff object. You have to deep clone the staff object in `editStaff` method.

## staff.component.ts

```
editStaff(staff) {
    this.editStaffData.staffInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(staff)); //Deep clone staff
    this.canEditStaff = !this.canEditStaff; 
}
```